# Save plot generated from python pandas with same name as of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have used pandas to generate a plot from a df which I want to save to a file

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/carsdataset.csv")

X=df.'columnname'.value_counts.(normalize=True)
X.plot.barh()
```

This gives me the figure(image) that I wanted. But I want to save this figure(image) at the same location with same filename(i.e 'carsdataset') so that I can run this code for any other csv file that I pick and it should automatically save the figure(image) with the same name(i.e name of the csv file)

Comment: Does this work? `X.plot.barh().get_figure().savefig('C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/carsdataset.png')`

Comment: it can work but if i change my dataset i will have to change it again and again

Comment: Perhaps the question isnt very clear. The challenge is the name? How are you reading it? In above example, it is hard coded !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on what Redox wrote.
Would this solve your problem?

```
import pandas as pd

dset_path = "C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/carsdataset.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(dset_path)

X=df.'columnname'.value_counts.(normalize=True)
X.plot.barh().get_figure().savefig(dset_path[:-3]+"png")
```